# Change table background dynamically angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

**How can I change the background of a table cell dynamically in HTML using AngularJS ?**

In the following code I want to show a table with a bunch of names and the including status of an object. The status can weather be `VALID` (green background) or `INVALID` (red background).

**Can this problem be solved in my `<td>` HTML tag or do I have to move on to CSS ?**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr ng-repeat="object in Cmd.items">
      <td>{{object.objectName}}</td>
      <td>{{object.objectStatus}}</td> //this background should be colored
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<tr ng-repeat="object in Cmd.items">
      <td>{{object.objectName}}</td>
      <td ng-class="{'red': object.objectStatus === 'invalid', 'green': object.objectStatus === 'valid'}">{{object.objectStatus}}</td> 
</tr>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gw8f9wgh/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-class

e.x. :

```
<div ng-class={'green-bg':isValid, 'red-bg':!isValid}> </div>
```

`green-bg` and `red-bg`
are css classes and isValid is property, where you know expression isValid or no

Answer (score 1):

**CSS :**

```
.invalid{
background-color:red;
}

.valid{
background-color:green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr ng-repeat="object in Cmd.items">
      <td>{{object.objectName}}</td>
      <td ng-class="object.objectStatus">{{object.objectStatus}}</td> //this background should be colored
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved both in the td tag or/and in your external css.

In Html

```
     <td ng-style="{'background': (object.objectStatus=='VALID') ? 'green' : 'red'}">
        {{object.objectStatus}}
      </td>
```

With external css You can use @oto lolua implementation